# netplan issues interface unmanageable

Tags: networking, netplan

I have a netplan like the enclosed one, however, when I do nmcli device status, enp5s0f7 is unmanaged, hence can't get IP address. Any idea?

```
root@tester-10:~$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
enp5s0f4         ethernet  connected               netplan-enp2s0f0
enp5s0f5         ethernet  connected               netplan-enp2s0f1
enp5s0f6         ethernet  unavailable             --
enp5s0f7         ethernet  unmanaged               --
```

This is a 4-port Intel NIC:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

If you do

```
root@tester-10:/etc/netplan$ sudo ifdown enp5s0f7
ifdown: interface enp5s0f7 not configured
```

---netplan.yaml file---

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0f0:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:98:65:e8
      set-name: enp5s0f4
    enp1s0f1:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:98:65:e9
      set-name: enp5s0f5
    enp1s0f2:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:98:65:e1
      set-name: enp5s0f6
    enp1s0f3:
      match:
        macaddress: ac:16:2d:98:65:eb
      set-name: enp5s0f7
      addresses: [10.0.128.1/24]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```